# Format Exception

Tags: c#

The below snipets are  from my Form1 code.  I keep getting a Format Exception because of my MessageBox.Show(…); declaration in my Stop() method.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?
        ...

```
    private TimeSpan iterationDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
    ...

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsGameOver = true;
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Game Over\n\nScore = {0}\n\n Time Duration =   {l}", score, iterationDuration));
        Application.Exit();
    }


    public void Start()
    {

        score = 0;
        IsGameOver = false;

        currentRedLightX = 0;
        currentRedLightY = 0;

        currentGreenLightX = width / 2;
        currentGreenLightY = height / 2;


        double minIterationDuration = SPEED; // 50 frames / sec

        //game loop
        while (!IsGameOver)
        {
            if (IsCollision())
            {
                score += 10;
            }

            DateTime startIterationTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            UpdateGameState();
            Render();
            DateTime endIterationTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan iterationDuration = endIterationTime - startIterationTime;
            if (iterationDuration.TotalMilliseconds < minIterationDuration)
                Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(minIterationDuration - iterationDuration.TotalMilliseconds));
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to declare a different `iterationDuration` in your game loop? Also you would do better to use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `.Now` (avoiding time zone and DST calculations) since you're just after an interval, or probably better still `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

Comment: A little less code and a little more of the error message would have helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an `{l}` (lower case L) not a 1...

Comment: Okay, Rup your right, I removed the second 'TimeSpan' declaration of iterationDuration in my Start() method. I also switched to DateTime.UtcNow.  I have VS 2008 and all the error message gives me is a hazard sign that states "Format Exception was unhandled".

Comment: I also made sure that I used a lower case L {l} and not a 1 in my MessageBox.Show(..) declaration.  She's still being difficult :-(

Comment: Originally, I used a try catch block to "handle" the exception, however, I am more interested in making sure that it doesn't throw an exception in the first place.

Comment: @user520312 "I also made sure that I used a lower case L {l} and not a 1" - try to reverse that. the L was the problem.

Comment: Woooooooow . . . boy I'm dense.   Worked like a charm. No more Format error, now all I have to do is figure out why time duration doesn't change from zero no matter how much time actually goes away. . .

Comment: lol good stuff, that exception gives you no help at all, glad it's sorted :D